# ngbDropdown Keyboard Arrow Keys Navigation

Tags: angular

When I added an additional layer `<div class="wrapper">` between **ngbDropdownMenu** and **ngbDropdownItem**, the arrow keys up/down navigation on the keyboard stopped working. Any advice? Thank you!

```
<div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" role="combobox" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropdown</button>
  <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <button ngbDropdownItem role="option">Action - 1</button>
      <button ngbDropdownItem role="option">Another Action</button>
      <button ngbDropdownItem role="option">Something else is here</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```